# Line before and after text in React Native app

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, react-native

How to style Text in React Native app like on the screenshot? It's like line before and line after the text. I have some ideas to style with :before and :after pseudo elements, but this elements don't exist in React Native.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COLKs.png)

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style your text with a horizontal rule appearing around it, you can put your text in a view like this:

```
<View>
      <View style={{alignSelf:'center',position:'absolute',borderBottomColor:'black',borderBottomWidth:1,height:'50%',width:'90%'}}/>
      <Text style={{alignSelf:'center',paddingHorizontal:5}}>Your text here</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Result not what I am expected. I get line trough, not line aroud. Your answer not correct :/

Comment: @SashaIgnashevich Are you sure that you have defined the text *after* the horizontal rule? If you do, then maybe give your text a background colour.

Comment: Correct answer for this is
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black', height: 2, flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center'}} />
    <Text style={{ alignSelf:'center', paddingHorizontal:5, fontSize: 24 }}>Your class</Text>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black', height: 2, flex: 1, alignSelf: 'center'}} />
</View>

Comment: How can I add space between the Text and decoration line. Any suggestion?https://i.stack.imgur.com/6woPN.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This works for me, Keep Coding

```
<View
  style={{
    flexDirection: "row",
    width: "85%",
    alignSelf: "center",
  }}
>
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: Colors.borderColor,
      height: 1,
      flex: 1,
      alignSelf: "center",
    }}
  />
  <Text
    style={{
      alignSelf: "center",
      paddingHorizontal: 5,
      fontSize: 14,
    }}
  >
    Or
  </Text>
  <View
    style={{
      backgroundColor: Colors.borderColor,
      height: 1,
      flex: 1,
      alignSelf: "center",
    }}
  />
</View>;
```